# PHP Fatal error when using laravel artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel

I was having problems using Laravel ver5.3. The `php artisan migrate` command worked fine locally. But The command does not listen on the server.

Server has PHP 7.0 / mariadb-10.0.x / UTF-8 / HTTP2.0 / Apache2.

this is error messages:

```
$ php artisan migrate

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: gethostbyaddr(): Address is not a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address in /home/prepend/funcall_excute/funcall_excute.php:307
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'gethostbyaddr()...', '/home/prepend/f...', 307, Array)
#1 /home/prepend/funcall_excute/funcall_excute.php(307): gethostbyaddr('')
#2 /home/prepend/funcall_excute/funcall_excute.php(166): __simplexi_prepend_funcall_create_file('/home/prepend/f...', 'funcall.txt')
#3 /home/prepend/funcall_excute/funcall_excute.php(10): __simplexi_prepend_funcall_get_whitelist()
#4 [internal function]: __fc_dispose(Array)
#5 /sue1924/Alzzle/vendor/symfony/console/Terminal.php(127): proc_open('stty -a | grep ...', Array, Array, NULL, NULL, Array)
#6 /sue1924/Alzzle/vendor/symfony/console/Terminal.php(70): Symfony\Component\Console\Terminal::getSttyColumns()
#7 /sue1924/Alzzle/vendor/symfony/console/Terminal.php(32): Symfony\Component\Console\Terminal::initDimensions()
#8 /sue1924/Alzzle/ven in /home/prepend/funcall_excute/funcall_excute.php on line 307
```

Has anyone solved this problem?

Comment: You would need to provide to us your DB_HOST .env variable (just change it a little for security reason, but don't remove any special chars)

Comment: `/home/prepend/funcall_excute/funcall_excute.php` looks suspiciously outside your project folder. What is that file?

Comment: @Bartłomiej Sobieszek The .env file has been modified to suit the situation. It seems to be another problem.

Comment: @apokryfos I thought it was something I created by the Larabel framework, not the files I added myself.

Comment: If you're using shared hosting it may be a file that the host injects to show adverts or something. If that's the case you should let them know that the file should not run in the CLI. If you're not using shared hosting then that's very concerning. Laravel will not create any files outside it's install folder and (perhaps) the tmp folder.

Comment: @apokryfos your're right. It's shared hosting.. I have to call the hosting company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem. I modified the local `.env` file to match the db on the server. And the command was executed locally.
Leave it for those who meet similar cases while using shared hosting.